# jQuery Async behavior in each-loop Fade-Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, async-await

i have a small problem with the async behavior of JS. My plan is to loop through some hidden images and fade them in and out with a specified FadeIn-, FadeOut-, and Staytime. I tried this code to do this:

```
jQuery('.fader img').each(function(x, y) {

    var faderImg = jQuery(y);
    faderImg.fadeIn(400).delay(1000).fadeOut(400);

});
```

My problem is that is doesnt wait for the execution of the last chained `fadeOut` Statement but insted doing the animation on every picture simultaneously. I tried it with async and await too but it dont fix my problem insted it has the same behavior as described above.

```
jQuery('.b1-img-fader img').each(async function(x, y) {

  var faderImg = jQuery(y);
  await faderImg.fadeIn(400).delay(1000).fadeOut(400);

});
```

Can someone help to to archive that every image is fading in after the image before is finished with fading out? The loop should only start the next turn if the functionality inside is finished.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can add `delay(x * 1800)` at the start. (remove async / await): `$(this).delay(x * 1800).fadeIn(400).delay(1000).fadeOut(400);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want each image to animate individually you need to delay each successive one with the time take to complete all previous images.

To do that you can get the delay amount by multiplying the index of the current image by the time the animation takes, like this:

```
$('.b1-img-fader img').each(function(index, el) {
  $(this).delay(index * 1800).fadeIn(400).delay(1000).fadeOut(400);
});
```